# Can't grant role permissions under sysadmin login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security

I'm trying to execute this script from Management Studio:

```
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[AdaptTemplate] TO [AdaptAdmin] AS [AdminSapr]
```

Execution fails with this message:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the role
>   'AdaptTemplate', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

There are existing roles `AdaptTemplate`, `AdaptAdmin` and user `AdminSapr` in database.
User `AdminSapr` is a member of `db_owner`. My current login (which I'm trying to execute script from) is a member of `sysadmin` server role.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't there any limitations in effect on your current role (as compared to the 'real' `sysadmin`)?

Comment: @dezso: no, there are no any limitations. Looks like `AdminSapr` hasn't sufficient rights to grant alter role.

Comment: Are you SURE you in the right database context? Do a select against the principals catalog view just to verify.

Comment: @ThomasStringer: yes, I'm sure. If I modify script a little to `GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[AdaptTemplate] TO [AdaptAdmin]` (so, instead of `AdminSapr` I'm using security context of my current login), then it being executed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the principal in the AS clause needs to have the permission with the "GRANT OPTION".  Running this will allow you to run your original code:

```
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[AdaptTemplate] TO [AdminSapr] WITH GRANT OPTION
```

My reading of Books Online made me think that what you're doing is right since AdminSapr is in the db_owner role but in testing I had to do something like the above to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues. It was mentionned to use the with grant options but correct me if I'm wrong but if you add with grant options you also permit that users to grant others permissions when it might not be what you want.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/189364)

Comment: Okay sorry about that. I just wanted the person to clarify the thing about with grant but I understand.

Comment: Your understanding of `WITH GRANT` is correct.