# SQL Server : GRANT REFERENCES Fails With Msg 15151 as Windows User with sysadmin role and also as 'sa'

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, permissions

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I execute this command:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON ASYMMETRIC KEY ::CorpKey to XYZZYEXT;
```

I get this result:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the asymmetric key 'CorpKey', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've checked a bunch of articles, including

[Can't grant role permissions under sysadmin login](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29969/cant-grant-role-permissions-under-sysadmin-login)

But I'm just not seeing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an `ASYMMETRIC KEY`, it is a `SYMMETRIC KEY`.
Change

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON ASYMMETRIC KEY
```

to

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON SYMMETRIC KEY
```